# Which is correct? What comes around goes around OR What goes around comes around?

Tags: word-choice

Which is correct?

1. What comes around goes around
2. What goes around comes around

Comment: Correct in what sense?

Answer (score 5):

The [standard phrase](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/What+goes+around,+comes+around) is the second. The implication is that actions often have a boomerang effect. You start something on an outward trajectory and it often comes back with unexpected consequences.